# pysd library ParseError

Tags: python, parsimonious, vensim

I'm using a library called `pysd` to translate `vensim` files to Python, but when I try to do it (library functions) I get a parse error but don't understand what it means.

This is my log.

---

```
ParseError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-9b0f6b9bac1f> in <module>()
      1 get_ipython().magic(u'pylab inline')
      2 import pysd
----> 3 model = pysd.read_vensim('201520_1A_Volare_Ev.Tecnica.itmx')

/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pysd/pysd.pyc in read_vensim(mdl_file)
     45     """
     46     from .vensim2py import translate_vensim
---> 47     py_model_file = translate_vensim(mdl_file)
     48     model = PySD(py_model_file)
     49     model.mdl_file = mdl_file

/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pysd/vensim2py.pyc in translate_vensim(mdl_file)
    651     for section in file_sections:
    652         if section['name'] == 'main':
--> 653             model_elements += get_model_elements(section['string'])
    654
    655     # extract equation components

/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pysd/vensim2py.pyc in get_model_elements(model_str)
    158     """
    159     parser = parsimonious.Grammar(model_structure_grammar)
--> 160     tree = parser.parse(model_str)
    161
    162     class ModelParser(parsimonious.NodeVisitor):

/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/parsimonious/grammar.pyc in parse(self, text, pos)
    121         """
    122         self._check_default_rule()
--> 123         return self.default_rule.parse(text, pos=pos)
    124
    125     def match(self, text, pos=0):

/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/parsimonious/expressions.pyc in parse(self, text, pos)
    108
    109         """
--> 110         node = self.match(text, pos=pos)
    111         if node.end < len(text):
    112             raise IncompleteParseError(text, node.end, self)

/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/parsimonious/expressions.pyc in match(self, text, pos)
    125         node = self.match_core(text, pos, {}, error)
    126         if node is None:
--> 127             raise error
    128         return node
    129

ParseError: Rule 'escape_group' didn't match at '' (line 1, column 20243).
```

Comment: Can you please post the code that lead to this error?

Comment: It is just an import statement : %pylab inline
import pysd
model = pysd.read_vensim('201520_1A_Volare_Ev.Tecnica.itmx')

Comment: It's good practice to post a minimum working example (MWE) in your post itself so people can easily view and reproduce the problem; it will make it much more likely for you to get a response.

Comment: @Daniel you mean a [mcve] (MCVE)?

Answer (score 0):

`.itmx` is an iThink extension, which unfortunately PySD doesn't support (yet). In the future, we'll work out a conversion pathway that lets you bring these in.